# Feature request: unflag

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Can we have the option to unflag a post? If an issue is resolved before a moderator gets around to handling the flag, it we be nice if we could get rid of the flag and save someone the time of looking at it.

Answer (score 9):

As of [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/323179) this is possible for post flags but [not comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285003/323179). Simply click on "flag" on the post to bring up the flag dialog, then "Retract Flag":

> [image: What it looks like when you have a mod flag you can retract]

Answer (score 1):

Users have the possibility to flag as invalid an existing flag; it would help if, after X users have flagged the flag as invalid, the post would not appear anymore between the flagged posts, and moderators would not need to mark the flag as invalid.