# Duplicate Comments & Un-flagging Comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, flagging

I've three related questions:

- If I believe a comment is essentially a duplicate of an earlier one, what is the proper etiquette, if any? I assume it's better to up vote a comment I agree with, rather than restate.
- If a duplicate comment is clutter, shouldn't we have an option to flag it as "duplicate"? Or is it so rare as to not require a special button?
- If we ever change our minds after flagging a comment, shouldn't we have an "undo flag" option? It could save the higher-ups some work.

A true story that motivated the issue:

While studying Susan's answer to [Can I say "take effort"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146234/can-i-say-take-effort)
I thought Wayne's comment was repeated, in essence, by Andrew, 4 hours or 2 comments, later.
In a moment of temporary hyper-criticism, I flagged Andrew's comment as "obsolete". What I really wanted was "redundant" (or to use the language of question flagging, "duplicate"). 
What I should have done was flag it as "other..." and then explained my true feelings.
Then, after being beset by feelings of remorse, I tried to *unflag* that which I had flagged.

Now, I *can* effectively undo an up- or down-vote to a question or answer by re-upvoting  or re-downvoting it. (I don't know if I can *unflag* a Q or A; I didn't understand the answer given to [Feature request: unflag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/feature-request-unflag).) 
However, an already-flagged *comment* is unflaggable! (Or is it unreflaggable? I'm agitated now, though normally unflappable.)

Especially embarrassing for me is that now I realize that Andrew was providing a *counterpoint* to Wayne's comment and there was no duplication. I'm so weighed down by remorse and embarrassment that I'm going to self-flag, flag and reflag myself vigorously until my flesh is raw.

Comment: Martin, please forgive me; I just rejected an edit of yours erroneously. I'm so sorry! Please do not let this add to your self-flagulation.

Comment: Hunh. I was totally unaware that there were options to flagging of comments. Anyway, comments are disposable so to speak and so I take flagging as marking a pretty serious violation. FLagging for comments as duplicate or obsolete seems like a lot of work for little benefit to anybody. Don't spend time thinking about flagging comments as much as fixing answers.

Comment: I think you mean *undeflaggable*. If it was my comment, don't worry: as Mitch says, comments are expendable and their deletion, accidental or otherwise, is an occupational hazard.