# How do you delete or undo a flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I made a mistake. I flagged a post I shouldn't have. It's not the end of the world, presumably the moderator will see it was a poor judgement call (I hope) but why can't I "go back" and delete my flag?

It seems silly to flag the same post to say: *Please ignore my first flag.*

Or can I do exactly that?

Related [Feature request: unflag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/feature-request-unflag) but aren't invalid flags something else entirely?

And one last question, what happened to the highlighted number that used to reside next to our profile avatars, the one  that requested our attention?

Comment: I believe the "silly" idea is the best idea. "Please ignore my first flag." That's what I'd do.

Comment: @kitfox and Hellion where is the answer, any answer in the duplicate question?!

Comment: @kitFox the duplicate question has no answers posted, if I had seen that question how would it have helped me? It says here below: *This question has been asked before and **already** has an answer*. This is false.

Answer (score 3):

If it's something horrible, you can post here, like you have done. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it.

This [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue) will hopefully answer your last question.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the link. Makes more sense now. But the answer to: Why can't I go back and *delete* my flag? Would it be so unreasonable? And now I know it *was* called a flag queue, a bit late now..

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's not an unreasonable feature request but it probably wouldn't rank highly on the StackExchange developers' list of things to do.